# Parametric solving a nonlinear equation and plotting answer

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I want to get `x` and `y` as a function of `z` in below nonlinear equations and plot `f[x]=Sqrt[x]` as a function of z, but my code does not work.

```
sol1 = NSolve[x == z + 1 - 0.7104*Sqrt[x + 0.0259*Exp[(x - 1.9098)/0.0259]], x]
sol2 = NSolve[y == z + 1 - 0.7104*Sqrt[y + 0.0259*Exp[(y - 3.9098)/0.0259]], y]
Plot[Sqrt[y]], {z, 0, 2.5}]
```

please help me to correct it. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with plotting `Sqrt[x]` as function of _z_? Clearly `Sqrt[x]` is **not** a function of _z_. If you want to plot the solution to your nonlinear equations please have a look at the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolvePlottingTheSolution.html)

Comment: Thank you @Sascha. in first equation, changing z will change x, thus we can say that x and Sqrt[x] are functions of z. I could not get answers using DSolve.

Comment: That might be true mathematically but this is not how _scoping_ works in Mathematica. The _symbols_ _x_ or _y_ used in `Plot` are not coupled with the _symbols_ _x_, _y_, _z_ inside `NSolve`. Have a look at the link I provided in my earlier comment and you will see how to get the results from `NSolve` (or any other `Solve` or `DSolve` related function) to be plotted.

Comment: A better source of information still might be this part of the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/UseRuleSolutions.html), it explains in detail what I tried to convey in my previous comments.

Answer (score 3):

```
soly[z_?NumericQ] := 
 NSolve[y == z + 1 - 0.7104*Sqrt[y + 0.0259*Exp[(y - 3.9098)/0.0259]], y, 
   Reals][[1]]
```

Note the form of the result, i.e., it is a [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html)

```
soly[1]

(*  {y -> 1.21647}  *)

Plot[Sqrt[y] /. soly[z], {z, 0, 2.5},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {z, Sqrt[y]})]
```

[image]